# How to get the upper limit of a integration?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have a probability distribution function which is the following:

```
f = @(x) h0 * (1/sqrt(2*pi*sig2)) .* exp(-(x-mh0).^2 / (2*sig2))+ (1-h0) * (1/sqrt(2*pi*sig2)) .* exp(-(x-mh1).^2 / (2*sig2));
```

I am doing this **Matlab**. Other than x, everything is constant.

The range for this function is (-4 , 8). I would like to divide this area into equal mass i.e. 1/10 ( 10 intervals, each with mass 1/10).

I am thinking about integrating it and check the upper limit as know the result of the integration. But I didn't find a way to do this?

Comment: I suggest numerically integrating it using MATLAB's standard ODE solvers. Give `ode45` a try. If the distribution function is too stiff to integrate, try `ode23`. Either ODE solver returns the discrete values of the integral, you would have to craft your own logic structure to approximate the equal mass points.

Answer (score 0):

A simple bisection search will find the splitting point simply if you're not worried about ultimate efficiency.  E.g., to split in two:

```matlab
sig2 = rand;
mh0 = rand;
h0 = rand;
mh1 = rand;
f = @(x) h0 * (1/sqrt(2*pi*sig2)) .* exp(-(x-mh0).^2 / (2*sig2))+ (1-h0) * (1/sqrt(2*pi*sig2)) .* exp(-(x-mh1).^2 / (2*sig2));
l = -4;
u = 8;
fprintf('total integral = %e\n', quad(f, l, u));
l0 = l;
u0 = u;
while u0 - l0 > 0.0001
  m = 0.5 * (l0 + u0);
  w = quad(f, l, m);
  if w > 0.5
    u0 = m;
  else
    l0 = m;
  end
end
m = 0.5 * (l0 + u0);
fprintf('integral to %e = %e\n', m, quad(f, l, m));
```

To split into 10 parts, recurse on the subparts.  First split at 0.5, then split the low interval at 0.2, then split the low part of that at 0.1, and the upper part at 0.3, and then the 0.3/0.5 interval to get 0.4.  Similarly for the upper parts.